# UK Fantasy Book series: Young boy finds magic coin that lets him see invisible magic people

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, witches

I remember reading a set of short books at UK secondary school in the late 80's.

It was set in contemporary time. A boy lived with his grandmother, who ran a guesthouse. He finds a coin that allows him to see invisible magic caricatures. One is a talking cat, Nottingham another is a pirate with a tricornered hat. He also meet a friendly witch who helps him to seal a group of bad witches in a magic pool at the end.

Does anyone remember the name of the books? My school never had the last books in the series and I was unable read them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this the ***[Tim and the Hidden People](https://www.goodreads.com/series/134443-tim-and-the-hidden-people)*** series (1974-1983) by Sheila K. McCullagh...?

According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_and_the_Hidden_People), the magical item that allows the protagonist, Tim, to see the titular hidden people is a key rather than a coin, but the premise is otherwise consistent with your description:

> The *Tim and the Hidden People* books are about a boy called Tim who lives in a house in The Yard. **The books begin with Tim finding a key which enables him to see the Hidden People, he befriends Tobias the black cat and has many adventures.** Tobias has a son, Sebastian, who also has special power as one of the "strange ones" - those who are half "ordinary folk" and half "Hidden people".

Looking at the individual books in the series, it appears that Tim meets a cat named Tobias in book A1, *[Tim and Tobias](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3211842-tim-and-tobias)* (1974), a ship's captain and/or pirate named Jory in book A3, *[Tim Meets Captain Jory](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10328514-tim-meets-captain-jory)* (1974), and some witches in book A5, *[Tim and the Witches](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22919414-tim-and-the-witches)* (1974).

Here's the cover of the first book, *Tim and Tobias*:

> [image: Front cover of "Tim and Tobias" (1974) by Sheila K. McCullagh.]

Comment: Hi Thanks that was just what I've been looking for, even looked up the other books and they are as I remember.